# Cypress, FusionAuth and Passwordless authentication

Tags: javascript, cypress

My app under tests generates a passwordless link that I use in order to log into the application. I wrote a simple Python script that returns the token I need in this URL and I just concatenate it to the string template .

Now, I'm trying to do the same with Cypress. I'm able to get the token and build the URL, but, I'm not able to login. I get an error related to a malformed url. If I go and get a code from my Python script, and replace the Cypress generated code, it works.

What might be wrong?

Comment: Can you share the entire error message? I know FusionAuth does some checking to try to prevent magic links from being called 2x, wonder if that is affecting things? https://github.com/FusionAuth/fusionauth-issues/issues/725 has more on that.

Comment: Oh, you might want to add the [fusionauth] tag as well.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.